# http content is showing in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, .net, http, iis, https

.Net Application is hosted on IIS Server and SSL is enabled on Default WebSite. All of the application's content is rendered on HTTPS. However, a few images in the same application and directory are being rendered over HTTP. I want everything to be rendered over HTTPS

Below is the log that I found for the images

```
onReceivedError: -8 error desc: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error url: http://XXXXXXX/Simulations/ModelSkins/352018174944853370.jpeg
```

I expect the above URL to be on https as below

```
https://XXXXXXX/Simulations/ModelSkins/352018174944853370.jpeg
```

Answer (score 1):

If your image are displayed like

```
<img src="http://XXXXXXX/Simulations/ModelSkins/352018174944853370.jpeg" alt="IIS" width="960" height="600" />
```

Please download and install URL rewrite：
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Then you could use outbound rule to rewrite these link by adding and modify following rule to your web .config system.webServer Section:

```
<rewrite>
    <outboundRules>
        <rule name="outbound rule">
            <match filterByTags="Img" pattern="http://XXXXXXX/(.*\.(png|jpeg))" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="https://XXXXXXX/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-outbound-rules-for-url-rewrite-module

[image]